# How is a chord progression with G#, D#m, F and G possible?

Tags: theory, chord-progressions, analysis, modulation

I was analyzing Gone Hollywood by Supertramp, and from around 0:22 a riff starts. The chords in the riff are G#, D#m/F#, F and G. The weird thing is that in the key of G# major the D# minor chord should have been a major chord, if i'm not mistaking. Because in this key the F# should be a G. Can someone explain this to me?

Later in the song, around 3:10, there is also a modulation from Cm to B, which seems also very strange to me. Can you explain that too?

Comment: Theory is a means to categorize certain parts of certain music. Everything can't be explained by theory, since most music isn't written with an explicit reference to theory.

Comment: Agreed, the 'hard and fast' mathematical rules of harmony and tonality are practically nonexistent and typically take a far, far backseat to cultural conventions in our music.  "Music theory" generally deals with categories of these conventions (and usually in a culturally biased way).  In my experience Jazz theorists are most likely to explain theory in a way that doesn't seem prescriptive, but only for about the first five minutes they try explaining it - then "Jazz theory" takes over and reduces everything to nonsensical wankery.

Answer (score 10):

The song could be on G# major; It would be easier to say it's in Ab major scale. These two are the same scale and they are called **Enharmonic scales**. (I'm using Ab because it is more common and easier to understand).

Here is how:

**Ab (G#)** -> 1st chord of your scale.
**Ebm (D#m)** -> 4th of the minor scale with the same name (Ab or G# minor) -- you are allowed to borrow a chord like this; borrowing the 4th chord from the minor scale is really common.
**F** -> Is the 6th chord of the Ab major scale. Now this chord *should* be a minor chord, but it is major one. In jazz, it is pretty common to play the sixth chord as dominant; this means that instead of Fm, the chord would be F7. (I'm not 100% sure this is the case here, but I cannot explain it otherwise).
**G**-> is the 7th chord of the scale. Now, this chord should be a half diminished one. I cannot tell you for sure what it is. It *could* be that the chord is Eb#5 (hence the natural B), with G in the bass. Eb is the 5th chord of your scale. The B could resolve up to C, which is the 3rd of your tonic, Ab.

Now, besides all the theory stuff, the composer *could* have simply followed the rule

> It sounded good and I like it, so I kept it.

Not everything has to be theory-explained. That's how music evolves and that's what makes it beautiful.

Comment: Just want to clarify that G# Major is an impossible key, therefore it must be Ab Major. Eb is the 5th degree or dominant chord, so that's normal. The F major chord is modal mixture if the chord quality doesn't serve a specific harmonic function (like a secondary dominant). Again, the G major chord is modal mixture unless it is the half-diminished leading-tone chord normally found in Ab major and functioning as such.

Comment: G# Major isn't really impossible, it crops up (albeit pretty rarely) in C# Major/Minor pieces that modulate to the Dominant key. It's a key where all pitches have a sharp except F, which has a double sharp. Don't get me wrong, it's still quite uncommon, and a lot of composers just use Ab major for readability, but Beethoven and Bach both occasionally used it.

But yeah, *starting* the piece is G# Major is strange, and it's an especially strange choice to apply to a piece that has no score.

Comment: Playing the VI chord as a dominant generally leads to the II, leading to V then to I - cycle of fourths.You're right - sounds good = is good. Theory only attempts to make sense of what happens, hence theory.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't listened to the excerpt, but it looks like a sort of extended Neapolitan. A passage on Wikipedia explains a possibility (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neapolitan_chord):

"Another such use of the Neapolitan is along with the German augmented sixth chord, which can serve as a pivot chord to tonicize the Neapolitan as a tonic. In C major/minor, the German augmented sixth chord is an enharmonic A♭7 chord, which could lead as a secondary dominant to D♭, the Neapolitan key area. As the dominant to ♭II, the A♭7 chord can then be respelled as a German augmented sixth, resolving back to the home key of C major/minor."

"In rock and popular music, examples of its use, notated as N and without 'traditional functional connotations,' include Fleetwood Mac's 'Save Me', Journey's 'Who's Crying Now', and The Rolling Stones' 'Mother's Little Helper'."

(Of course, based on this, it would seem a sort of ornamental minor-izing note gets slipped into the excerpt)

Answer (score 0):

To add to Shevliaskovic's answer, after listening to the song, I notice that after the G major chord that you cited is followed by C minor.  So that can explain the eventual move to G: To resolve to C minor (a V/i relationship).

I think if you consider the G# chord to really be an Ab, it might put the two chords Cm and Ab into a closer relation.  As for the F?  Is it IV of i in C minor, or VI/I in Ab?  Either way, it's an altered (and beautiful) chord.  F minor, which fits diatonically with these two keys, finally appears around 2:53.

Melodically, during the C minor vamp, the note *Ab* is very prevalent.  It's so far a tug-of-war (so to speak) between C minor and Ab major.

Next, Eb major is emphasized (III/C or V/Ab), resolving to the beginning section in Ab, but then coming back almost as a tonic at the end!

So we have three harmonically closely-related sections of this song that are C minor, Ab, and Eb.  Perhaps this could be best thought of as a fantasia.  It ends on Eb but I'm not convinced that is the key.

Answer (score 0):

listenin for the very first time (although I know and like them) ...it sounds like the beginning is in the key of G# with a Mixolydian flava, as the second chord sounds like a F# -with notes that seem to be taken from a Phrygian mode that connects the F# with F (Phrygian Dominant) - So, just for the first three important chords, it's all about mixed modes composition style. Immediately after, I hear a sudden G major , and I would say it's a case of superfast change of tonal center - but the G is also used as a Dominant to resolve on a C minor (7?)